# How to get the attached file of a received mail using python and store it in a blob property field

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, email-attachments, payload

I am trying to get the attached file from the received mail and store it as Blob property in the GAE datastore. I am using Google app engine Python.

The file should be added to datastore only if the file is a excel file. Following code shows the method i have used for this. In that class '**mail_message.attachments' will give a list of attachments of the received mail. From that we can get only the file name and file content . But here i have to get the format of the file for checking whether it's a excel file.** so that's why i have used the following method.

```
 class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
   def receive(self, mail_message):
     file_format_supported=['application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.ms-excel']
     for payload_no in range(len(mail_message.original.get_payload())):
        one_payload = mail_message.original.get_payload(payload_no)
        if one_payload.get_content_type() in file_format_supported:
            uploadfile=Files()
            uploadfile.temp_file=one_payload
            uploadfile.put()
```

this code gives me the error

> Property temp_file must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not instance)

what i want to do converting the payload type as "str instance" to store it as blob property.

****Is there any other method to find the file type after getting the attachment list using mail_message.attachments. File content got from this attachment list can be stored to GAE datastore as blob property after decoding **.**